# Storage::move giving "File not found at path:" Laravel with Ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

I want to move some file with

```
Storage::move('posts/temp/'.$val,'photos/'.$post->id.'/'.$val);
```

but it gives me the

```
File not found at path: home/vagrant/Code/......
```

is there some special configuration to look for? Btw, the file is indeed at the not found path.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `disk()` detail that you are using for example if you are using amazon `s3` you need to add `disk('s3')` before move so the code will be:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->move('posts/temp/'.$val,'photos/'.$post->id.'/'.$val);
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to change to:

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => public_path(),
        ],
```

Comment: This is not correct every time.  public_path() returns /public path. If you saving files within /storage ... code will return the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I stored files in storage app folder (Storage/app/temp_files) for finding the files I tried public_path(), storage_path(), url() but none of this worked for me. But at the end using PHP native function [**rename()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) its worked like a charm.
Here is my example of how I implement this

```
rename(storage_path("app\\temp_files\\$fileNames"),storage_path("app\\post\\$fileNames"));
```

Where the 1st argument is for the **old path** and 2nd for the **new path** e.g.

```
rename($oldPath, $newPath);
```

> Note: rename will be move(delete file from old location) your file
>   from old location to new location