# Laravel File not found at path but it does exist

Tags: php, laravel, file, storage

Getting the following error in console when attempting to get a files contents:

> [League\Flysystem\FileNotFoundException]   File not found at path:
>   C:/wamp64/www/lion/resources/generate/json/Car.json

When I copy and paste that exact path in explorer it opens the json file fine.

Here is my code:

```
$this->json = json_encode(Storage::get(resource_path('generate/json/'.$this->argument('model').'.json')));
```

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385056/storagemove-giving-file-not-found-at-path-laravel-with-ubuntu

Comment: Seems to be permission issue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured it out.

`Storage::get` actually uses the path relative to the filesystem disk configuration, therefore the error message itself is misleading.

I've corrected the issue by simply using `file_get_contents()` instead.

Comment: i have this issue for delete. when i get from client and save is ok and save filename in db but when i want to delete $this->logo is relative url path i dont know why?

Answer (score 8):

As others pointed out `Storage::get` indeed uses the path relative to the filesystem disk configuration, by default the `local` driver is used (`config/filesystems.php`):

```
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app'),
],
```

So if you are using the `local` driver and your file resides at `app/public/yourfile.ext` for example then the call to `Storage` should be:

```
Storage::get('public/yourfile.ext');
```

Comment: Thank you. I was missing "public/myFolder/myFile.txt".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->json = json_encode(app_path('/resources/generate/json/Car.json');
```