# File does not exist at path /module.json

Tags: php, laravel

I want to delete my caches I got this error message:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

`File does not exist at path /module.json`

Comment: `php artisan config:cache` , `php artisan route:clear` have you refer this one? https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules/issues/371

Comment: I got the same error.

Comment: `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: I got the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769693/laravel-file-not-found-at-path-but-it-does-exist

Comment: 1. Can you please show the full error stacktrace? 2. Does or did a file `module.json` ever exist in your project? 3. Where in your project is the file referenced, did you search? 4. Do you have any idea what the 'module' is, are you trying to use some package?