# how can I solve the "file not found at path" error?

Tags: php, laravel, storage, laravel-7

I write a function in my medium model to get the visibility of files and I did that that with accessors

my function :

```
public function getVisibilityAttribute()
{
 return Storage::getVisibility(storage_path('app/' . $this->getOriginal('path')));
// the path comes from database and here is 'public/test/user.jpg'
}
```

after I fetch my data from database to show the files , I get this error :

```
exception: "League\Flysystem\FileNotFoundException"
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\vendor\league\flysystem\src\Filesystem.php"
line: 389
message: "File not found at path: C:/xampp/htdocs/admin/storage/app/public/test/user.jpg"
```

but the user.jpg exists at that path and i can access the image by browser .

so what should i do to solve this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel File not found at path but it does exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769693/laravel-file-not-found-at-path-but-it-does-exist)

Answer (score 0):

you can first check if you run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then this works fine:

```
return Storage::disk('public')->getVisibility('test.txt');
```

File location in:

```
/storage/app/public/test.txt
```

Adapt your getVisibilityAttribute function accordingly and can try it out.