# Symfony oneup league flysystem file not found

Tags: symfony, flysystem

I am uploading files using `oneup/flysystem-bundle` and `vich/uploader-bundle` and that works fine.

When trying to delete a file with

```
 $this->filesystem->delete($path)
```

it throws error saying that file not found, although the path is correct.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769693/laravel-file-not-found-at-path-but-it-does-exist) suggests that this may be due `$this->filesystem` using a relative path.

That may be the case, but relative to what?

Initially I used `$path` as being the full absolute path. Then I tried a few variants of relative path, but nothing worked.

I know I could just use `unlink`, but I want to understand this.

This how the config file looks like:

```
oneup_flysystem:
  adapters:
    category_image:
        local:
            directory: "%kernel.project_dir%/public/images/category"
  filesystems:
    category_image_filesystem:
        adapter: category_image
        mount: category_image_filesystem
```

EDIT: Solution as proposed by Bossman

on config:

```
    category_image:
        local:
            directory: "%kernel.project_dir%/public/images/category"
            permissions:
                file:
                    public: 0o644
                    private: 0o600
                dir:
                    public: 0o755
                    private: 0o700
```

on controller:

```
      $filename = $oldImage->getFilename();
        if ($filename && $this->filesystem->has($filename)) {
            $this->filesystem->delete($filename);
        }
```

Comment: Is it treating this as the relative path `"%kernel.project_dir%/public/images/category"` if so then have you tried the filename directly, like `$this->filesystem->delete('fileName.jpg')`

Comment: Thanks but that did not work either.

Comment: Have you set the visibility of the files and directories, according to the doc they are set to private by default. Try adding `visibility: public and directory_visibility: public` to the filesystems directive, shown [here](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupFlysystemBundle/blob/main/doc/index.md) in step 3.

Comment: Right you are! Note only that this being `oneup` the permission setup is different as https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupFlysystemBundle/blob/main/doc/adapter_local.md. Otherwise I edited my question to include the implementation of your solution. Do put that as an answer and I will accept it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original [Flysystem](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupFlysystemBundle/blob/main/doc/index.md) has visibility directives within the config file for file and directory visibility, by default they are *private*. Make these *public*.

As shown in [step 3](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupFlysystemBundle/blob/main/doc/index.md#step3-configure-your-filesystems):

```
# app/config/config.yml
oneup_flysystem:
    adapters:
        my_adapter:
            local:
                location: "%kernel.root_dir%/cache"

    filesystems:
        my_filesystem:
            adapter: my_adapter

            # optional - defines the default visibility of files: `public` or `private` (default)
            visibility: private

            # optional - defines the default visibility of directories: `public` or `private` (default)
            directory_visibility: private
```

For more control the file and directory visibility properties can be set like [this](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupFlysystemBundle/blob/main/doc/adapter_local.md), like [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod):

```
# app/config/config.yml
oneup_flysystem:
    adapters:
        my_adapter:
            local:
                location: "%kernel.root_dir%/../uploads"
                lazy: ~ # boolean (default "false")
                writeFlags: ~
                linkHandling: ~
                permissions:
                    file:
                        public: 0o644
                        private: 0o600
                    dir:
                        public: 0o755
                        private: 0o700
```