# How to rename a image on server location using laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to rename a file name and i want old name should be change.

```
    I have tried Storage::move('old_image path','new image path');

    $file=ClientDocument::where('id',$request->id)->first();

    Storage::move(url('/').'/file/'.$file->file,url('/').'/file/'. $request->file);
```

When I am using this Storage::move(url('/').'/file/'.$file->file,url('/').'/file/'. $request->file);

It is showing me an error

File not found at path: https:/test.heartlandpar.com/public/file/99d0e66a-68e2-482c-8723-1bba1d35b871_rw_1920.jpg

But when i am hitting this url in browser image is open in browser.

Comment: Could you please post the error

Answer (score 0):

You can use the condition to check it the file is exists in that place or not . 
if the file exists, then show error . Or store the file .

```
$exists = Storage::disk('spaces')->exists('FMSuploads/VehicleDoc/'.$file->getClientOriginalName());
                        if($exists){
                            \Session::flash('error', 'File name already exist');
                            return redirect()->back()->withInput();
                        }
                       else{
                        Storage::disk('spaces')->putFileAs('FMSuploads/VehicleDoc', $file, $file->getClientOriginalName(), 'public');
                         log::info('document uploaded successfullly');
                       }
```

Or check this post [File rename in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385056/storagemove-giving-file-not-found-at-path-laravel-with-ubuntu)

Comment: But i want to rename a file which already in my public path folder.

Comment: @JogenderDelaine I have modified my question. Please check it

Comment: can you explain about disk('spaces') . I am using first time.

Comment: @JogenderDelaine It is used to specify the disk which you are using in filesystem . Check the file in /config/filesystems.php . It has the filesystems config . For example, if you have the storage space in aws it will have s3 ,. if the file is in local  , it is configured inside 'local' or public.

Comment: I checked my file , in the file there is local. so now i need to use local at place of s3.

Comment: @JogenderDelaine Have you updated your s3 config api keys and others in .env file or any other config files?